# VueJS Single File Component with typescript: Unable to find module stuff.vue

Tags: typescript, webpack, vue.js, vuejs2, webpack-2

I have a simple project structure:

/src/app2/main.ts
/src/app2/components/lib.ts
/src/app2/components/stuff.vue

With webpack, vue-loader, and ts-loader.

main.ts has:

```
import Vue = require('vue');
import  Component from './components/lib'

new Vue({
  el: '#app2'

});
```

When trying to build this with 1 webpack entry for `/src/app2/main.ts`, the error generated is:

```
ERROR in C:\temp\vuetest2\proj\src\app2\components\lib.ts
(2,25): error TS2307: Cannot find module './stuff.vue'.

ERROR in ./src/app2/main.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './components/lib' in 'C:\temp\vuetest2\proj\src\app2'
 @ ./src/app2/main.ts 3:12-39
```

If I change the entry point to `src/app2/components/lib.ts`, it will build.  I'm at a loss as to why main.ts won't build.

Contents of lib.ts:

```
import Vue = require('vue');
import Stuff  = require('./stuff.vue');


let o = {
   Stuff
}

let componentLibrary = {
  components: o,
  registerExternal: function(v:any) {
    for(var k in o) {
        v.component(o[k].name, o[k]);
    }
  },
  registerInternal: function() {
    for(var k in o) {
        Vue.component(o[k].name, o[k]);
    }
  }
}

export default componentLibrary;
```

Stuff.vue is just a simple single file vue component.

Comment: Try to modify your main.ts, like this `new Vue({
  el: '#app2',
  render: (h) => h(Component)
});` I guess `Component` is main component

Comment: It won't compile in webpack.  Your suggestion won't make a difference with the compilation as far as I know.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: I did, I'll see if I can post my answer later or confirm the one below.. Just haven't had much time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to : https://github.com/vuejs/vue-class-component/blob/master/example/webpack.config.js

Try adding `appendTsSuffixTo` ts-loader option in your `webpack.config.js`

webpack2

```
{
    test: /\.ts$/,
    exclude: /node_modules|vue\/src/,
    use: [{
            loader: 'ts-loader',
            options: {
                appendTsSuffixTo: [/\.vue$/]
            }
        }]
},
```

Comment: I have this already, but my .vue modules still can't be found from index.ts. They can be found from other .vue files though!

Answer (score 3):

You can reference on [this PR](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-loader/pull/687) on github. Actually that's not a bug, just a usage problem.

I assume that you want to write SFC with `<script lang="ts">`, `<script lang="tsx">`, `*.ts` for utils functions & classes, and `*.tsx` for functional pure component.

ts-loader accpets only `*.ts` or `*.tsx` files to compile (otherwise it would cause an error that file not found). So ts-loader has two options: `appendTsSuffixTo` and `appendTsxSuffixTo`. These two options accept an array of regexp to match which files you want to compile. (Here we give ts-loader the *.vue files that already processed by vue-loader to compile).

I assume that you use *.ts.vue for `<script lang="ts">` SFC vue file while *.tsx.vue for `<script lang="tsx">` SFC vue file. ts-loader should be configured as below:

```
  {
    test: /\.tsx?$/,
    use: [
      {
        loader: 'babel-loader'
      },
      {
        loader: 'ts-loader',
        options: {
          appendTsSuffixTo: [/\.ts\.vue$/],
          appendTsxSuffixTo: [/\.tsx\.vue$/]
        }
      }
    ],
    exclude: /node_modules/
  },
```

This means, normal *.ts and *.tsx files pass to ts-loader will transpiled and then be sent to babel-loader for further compile. And other files end with `.ts.vue` will be suffixed `.ts` as `*.ts.vue.ts`, and end with `.tsx.vue` to be `*.tsx.vue.tsx`. These files all passed from vue-loader. Remember ts-loader only accept `.ts` and `.tsx` files.

But vue-loader is not smart enough, `<script lang="xxx">` will trigger vue-loader append xxx-loader for further compile, and `<script lang="tsx">` will make vue-loader append tsx-loader, which is not exist in the world.

Fortunately we can configure vue-loader's `options`:

```
  const loaders = {}
  loaders.tsx = ['babel-loader', 'ts-loader']
  loaders.ts = loaders.tsx
  {
    test: /\.vue$/,
    loader: 'vue-loader',
    options: { loaders }
  },
```

After that webpack config is completed. For tsx support, you should install some JSX types and write a related .d.ts file

You can check [this repo](https://github.com/Plasmatium/amazing-canvas-collection) on github for more details.

Good luck!

Comment: I don't see vue-loader options in that repo, where is that placed?